# why the data object of datataskwithurl is receiveing null?

Tags: ios, json, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization, jsonresponse

I want to fetch some data from my backend to my app. I wrote following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/books"];
    config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    //curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="replace-with-token"'
    [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@"Token token=\"7601ea35c7eaf067fefe\""}];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSError *error1=nil;
        NSArray *JSON=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];
    }

      ] resume];
```

I check the response object and I got 200,seems the fetch request went well. but I got the null as for requested data. I think sth from parsing data went wrong. here is it is an example of what I expected to recieve.I aslo put the example out put into JSON viewer http://jsonviewer.stack.hu . it shows sth like {} at the first side, but when I open it, it shows data correctly.

```
[
     {
        "id": 437,
        "name": "alchemist",
        "description": "story book.",
        "favorite": false,
        "difficulty": 3,
        "created_at": "2014-09-29T10:43:00.072Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-11-26T11:53:58.451Z",
        "photo": {
          "url": "https://amazon-/uploads/books/photo/437/alchemist.jpg",
          "thumbnail_url": "https://amazon-books.amazonaws.com/uploads/recipe/photo/437/alchemist-PC.jpg"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Does any one know the reason?
This is an update for my question, here it is the nsurlresponse object:

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 11 Jul 2015 15:26:58 GMT";
    Etag = "\"d751713988987e9331980363e24189ce\"";
    Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2015-04-13)";
    Via = "1.1 vegur";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Request-Id" = "8e1abb2e-2526-4d10-99e7-d553b51457fd";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.125302";
    "X-Ua-Compatible" = "chrome=1";
    "X-Xss-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you received is not in JSON format. You can check it with following code:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog("%@", string);
```

Comment: I've tried this as well. I keep getting this [ ] as a response.

Comment: Did you place code above in completion handler block? I tried your code and received HTML page, with information: "The page you requested no longer exists or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Yes , I did. thanks for checking my code,This is an example of my code and my response.  here it is a right url which I am using in my code: "http://hyper-recipes.herokuapp.com/recipes"

Comment: Yes, the response is only [ ] now. There is nothing wrong with your code, as I can see, maybe the parameters aren't right. You can check your request on online services (e.g. hurl.it) to see if the request is regular before adding it to your code.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the online service, It looks very helpful. It seems my request and it' parameter are fine.